# Pull all master branches

Tags: git

I have this sequence to update my repository

```
git pull origin master:master
git submodule update --init
git submodule foreach git pull origin master:master
```

Notice that the focus is updating all master branches without touching the current branch

Is it possible to the above in just one line?

My first thought was this:

git pull --recurse-submodules origin master:master

but if I specify a branch the `recurse-submodules` is ignored.

Most things I tried `git submodules` either ignore the root repository or modify the branch of the submodules